# Functional way of implementing DB access with additional logic

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, scalikejdbc

Currently, my goal is to communicate with DB using CRUD approach. Between simple operation i may have some extra steps (additional business-logic which may throw some errors).

```
import cats.effect.IO
import scalikejdbc._

IO(NamedDB(MyDB) localTx {
  implicit session => {
   val x = for {
      a <- IO(select()) // Option[Something]  (1)
      _ <- IO(log(a)) // Option[Something]  (2)
      _ <- IO(insert()) // Something (3)
      _ <- IO(insert()) // Something (4)
      c <- IO(select()) // Option[Something] (5)
      r <- IO(fileSystemOperation(a, c)) // (6)
      _ <- operation(r) // Either[Throwable, Unit] (7)
    } yield ()

    x.unsafeRunSync() // (8)
  }
}).attempt.unsafeRunSync() match { // (9)
  case Left(value) => println("Error")
  case Right(value) => println("Success") // in reality i want to return some result here
}
```

The first problem comes in `(2)`: i got error:

> Error type mismatch;  found   : cats.effect.IO[Unit] 
>   required: Option[?]
>                 _ <- IO(log(a))

But if i log result of any insert (`(3)` or `(4)`) then all is ok. Probably, it's because of difference in result type `Option[Something]` vs `Something`, but i thought that it would be the same as this:

```
for {
    a <- Option(1)
    ....
}
```

The second question is how to correcly handle errors in `(7)` to rollback transaction? Do i have to use pattern matching and do something like this:

```
operation(r) match {
    case Left(e) => throw e
}
```

or i can throw error inside my `operation` and return `Unit` instead of `Either[Throwable, Unit]`?

Also, i have question about `(8)` and `(9)`. Is it a correct way to start actual processing and handle any error or not?

I tried to do the same steps using this approach:

```
select() match {
    case Some(_) =>
        .....
        operation(r) match {
            case Left(e) => throw e
            case Right(_) => ....
        }
    case None => ....
}
```

But in result i got too deep `match-case` clauses and it was hard to read and understand.
I'm new to FP, but i want to implement this in FP way.

Comment: Could you create a [MCVE] of your problem?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov ok, i'll add runnable example

Comment: I think you have several question. It might be good to break them into separate questions on this site, too. You're more likely to get responses to small, constrained questions.

Comment: @erip, yes, probably, you are right. I will decompose this question into severla smaller

Comment: I'm not sure if you have flexibility in switching around tools, but people _really like_ [doobie](https://tpolecat.github.io/doobie/) for JDBC programming. You might find it useful and compositional.

Comment: I will look at this, thank you!